# SQL query that combines 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my Access database I have a three different tables based on a pizza company:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What query can I write to show the names of all the delivery staff and the number of items they have delivered? I understand I have to use table aliases but as I am new to SQL I am having problems finding a solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select StaffId, fName, lName, sum(Quantity) 
from DeliveryStaff ds, Orders o, OrderItems oi 
where StaffId = DeliveryStaffId 
  and o.OrderId = oi.OrderId 
group by StaffId, fName, lName
```

Comment: Worst idea not to do a join of the tables.

Answer (score 5):

In `MS SQL`, i think the below code will work.

```
SELECT  DS.StaffId,COUNT(OI.OrderId) [Count]
FROM    DeliveryStaff DS
JOIN    Orders O ON DS.StaffId = O.DeliveryStaffId
JOIN    OrderItems OI ON O.OrderId = OI.OrderId
GROUP BY DS.StaffId
```